# What gem you recommend for a State machine that works well with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

Im using Rubystasm *gem "rubyist-aasm"*, the thing is that it keeps showing me warning messages, and it is pretty annoying.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Base.named_scope has been deprecated, please use Base.scope instead.
```

What I want, is the same functionality but without the warning messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine). It has most progress. 
The all state machines gems at [ruby-toolbox.com](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines.html)

Comment: Thanks! I think I will migrate the actual code to this gem and give it a try.